# Unir resultados de duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, select, join

Preciso fazer um `SELECT` em duas tabelas e unir os resultados.

Minhas tabelas são "cursos_aula" e "cursos_progresso". Na tabela "cursos_aula" tenho todas as aulas de um curso. Na tabela "cursos_progresso" tenho registro apenas se o cliente iniciou (finalizando ou não) a aula. Ou seja, preciso que liste todas as aulas do curso X e exiba o status que estiver na tabela "cursos_progresso". Se o registro não existir deveria retornar `NULL`, porém só estou conseguindo unir os resultados que tem correspondência nas duas tabelas.

Minha *Query* atual é:

```
SELECT a.id, a.aula, p.status
FROM cursos_aulas a
LEFT JOIN cursos_progresso p ON p.id_aula=a.id
WHERE a.id_curso='$idCurso' AND p.cpfcnpj='$cpfcnpj'
ORDER BY a.sequencia
```

Alguém sabe o que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua tabela cursos_aulas é `ID` a chave primária ?
Porque no `WHERE` você coloca `a.id_curso`.

Tenta assim:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.aula,
    p. STATUS
FROM
    cursos_aulas a
LEFT JOIN cursos_progresso p ON p.id_aula = a.id
AND
    p.cpfcnpj = '$cpfcnpj'
WHERE
    a.id = '$idCurso'
ORDER BY
    a.sequencia
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, o campo ID é a chave primária. Eu testei sua Query aqui e funcionou mais ou menos... Retornou todos os registros da tabela "cursos_aulas", porém no campo "status" só apareceu 1 registro da tabela "cursos_progresso", sendo que existem 4 registros nessa tabela.

Comment: Adaptei sua Query com a minha e deu certo. Ao invés de deixar os 2 AND no LEFT JOIN, deixei apenas um dos AND e adicionei um WHERE. Funcionou. Segue a Query que deu certo: SELECT a.id, a.aula, p.status
FROM cursos_aulas a
LEFT JOIN cursos_progresso p ON p.id_aula=a.id AND p.cpfcnpj='$cpfcnpj'
WHERE a.id_curso='$idCurso'
ORDER BY a.sequencia

Comment: Era isso o que eu ia falar para você deixar o AND apenas no CPF. Beleza...! Parabéns